# how to edit blank lines inside text file using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

hi i'm trying to fill blank lines in a text file,but only line 69 is being edited knowing that all the lines are blank,this is my code please help

```
Public Sub labelstrings()
    Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(del.filename)
    Dim v As Integer
    For v = 0 To 69 
        ReDim lines(v)
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lines(v)) Then

            lines(v) = "ali"
            File.WriteAllLines(del.filename, lines)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

i also tried:

```
Public Sub labelstrings()
    Dim content As String
    content = File.ReadAllText(del.filename)
    content = content.Replace(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content), "ali")
    File.WriteAllText(del.filename, content)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process the **entire array**, then re-write the file only **once** afterwards.  There is no need to re-dim the array, and you should use its upperbound instead of a hard-coded value:

```
Public Sub labelstrings()
    Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(del.filename)
    For v As Integer = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lines(v)) Then
            lines(v) = "ali"
        End If
    Next
    File.WriteAllLines(del.filename, lines)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,but id didn't work nothing was written to the file,note that my text file is completely blank.

Comment: Then you either haven't described your problem correctly, or you've implemented the solution incorrectly.  The code above correctly changed all blank lines in my test file to "ali"...